# Flutter LayoutBuilder BoxConstraints(unconstrained) inside Positioned inside Stack (BoxConstraints forces an infinite width and infinite height)

Tags: flutter, flutter-positioned, flutter-layoutbuilder, boxconstraints

I have an `Stack` with multiple children, some of them inside of `Positioned` with different vertical and horizontal values setted.

Some of the childs need to know the `Stack` constraints in order to measure themselves based on the available width and height.

I found out that if you use a `LayoutBuilder` inside of a `Positioned` and the `left`, `top`, `right` or `bottom` are setted the `BoxConstraints` would be *unconstrained*

I need a way to get the `Stack` size (**dynamic**, depends on where the `Stack` is used) in its childrens, and also to be able to position them wherever I want, bottom/right, top/left etc...

Here you have a minimal reproducible example with the **BoxConstraints forces an infinite width and infinite height** error caused by **BoxConstraints(unconstrained)**:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(
          bottom: 0, // <- commenting this the constraints would have a proper size, in this 
                     // particular example the full screen width and height.
          child: LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
              return Container(
                // BoxConstraints forces an infinite width and infinite height error since 
                // constraints are unconstrained so width and height are infinite
                width: constraints.maxWidth,
                height: constraints.maxHeight,
                color: Colors.redAccent,
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

I'm aware that removing `bottom:0` and using `alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft` will solve the issue on this example, but as I said, I have multiple children, if I want another child on the top, this solution wont work for both.

Comment: If I understand your question, try using an `Align` widget instead of `Positioned`

Comment: @MendelG thank you, It's working, I didn't try `Align` on my simplified example, I did try `Align` on my original code but got what it seems a non related issue. I'll wait until tomorrow so you can post the answer, if not I will post it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the widget with an `Align` widget instead of a `Positioned`:

```dart
 Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: LayoutBuilder(
                builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
                  return Container(
                    // BoxConstraints forces an infinite width and infinite height error since
                    // constraints are unconstrained so width and height are infinite
                    width: constraints.maxWidth,
                    height: constraints.maxHeight,
                    color: Colors.redAccent,
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
```